# How to cut fasta sequence at specific numbers and generate ORFs

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a file as shown below:

```
 CDS             join(36..56,37..67)
 CDS             36..183
 CDS             457..565
 CDS             join(505..519,521..596)
 CDS             join(577..591,725..770)
 CDS             join(516..591,725..899)
 CDS             508..556
 CDS             571..841
 CDS             complement(619..788)
 CDS             843..863
```

I want to print the specific number of nucleotide range as in the file (the sequence is read from another file "sequence.fasta").
For example for sequence.fasta file as :

```
>gi1234 HIVgenome|NC_909999.1
AACTGCGTGTGTGTCCACACAACACTGGGGGACACACAACAACAACACTGGGGGACACACTGGGACAACACTGGGGGACAGGACACTGTACAACACTGGGTGTGTCGGGACAGTACACATGTTGGGGGGGTGTGTCGGACAACACTGGGGGACATGTGTGTACAACACTGGGGGACAGTGACGACGACAACACTGGGGGACACGAGCGTTGTGAGCAGGTGACAACACTGGGGGACAGTGTTTTTACAACACTGGGGGACATTTTTGAGCAGCGACGCAGCGTTGTGGGGTGTGTCGGAAGGTGTGTCGTGTGTCGTGTGTC
```

Outputp should be

```
36  -  56   ACAACAACAACACTGGGGGAC 

37  -  67   CAACAACAACACTGGGGGACAACACTGGGAC
```

& so on...

till

```
843 - 863   GTGT....
```

What would be easiest way to do so through shell scripting?

Comment: Is your file an actual fasta file or just  a single line of sequence?

Comment: A fasta file usually has a header line (`>some_ID some text here`) followed by a newline, followed by sequence data with newlines, until the next header line. How do we know what fasta entry should be read? There are no IDs in the first file.

Comment: actual fasta file

Comment: The sequence.fasta would be the one for which the cut (36..56, 37..67) type file would be generated

Comment: So there's a header line? And only one sequence?

Comment: yes
example
>gi1234 HIVgenome|NC_909999.1

Answer (score 1):

This question requires a larger programming effort than may be offered by this forum (I do this kind of programming for a living).

The [DDBJ/ENA/GenBank file format](http://www.insdc.org/files/feature_table.html) (the first file in the question) is complex and allows CDSs (the coding parts of a genomic sequence) to be not just plain or joined, but complemented and combinations thereof. Furthermore, the positional coordinates may have [modifiers](http://www.insdc.org/files/feature_table.html#3.4.3) that, for a generic solution, would need to be handled.

You would be better off asking a local bioinformatician (or programmer) or in a bioinformatics forum, such as the StackExchange [Bioinformatics site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/). They will point you to existing tools for doing this sort of thing, or, knowing bioinformaticians, give you some quirky BioPerl/BioPython script that will probably work more often than not ;-)

One *possible* route would be to use the [GenBank Feature Extractor](http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/genbank_feat.html), but using it online will most likely not be the best option for anything but small datasets.

Comment: One simple way that I figured out is as below. It is not a professional way of doing the said work but will work for time being.
awk '{print $2}' file1*(havingCDS regions)* >NUM

grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,}' NUM > Nos

tr -d '\n' <sequence.fasta > temp

wc -l Nos > length

len=`awk '{print $1}' length`

for i in $(seq 1 2 $len)
do
a=`awk "NR==$i" Nos`
b=`awk "NR==$(($i+1))" Nos`
echo $a"  "$b >>start_stop
cut -c $a-$b temp >> genes
paste start_stop genes >> RESULT

Answer (score 0):

Even though I gave my previous answer, I have looked at the sub-problem of extracting a particular sub-sequence out of a fasta file.  The solution is in two parts:

1. An `sh` shell script that does the command line parsing, and calls...
2. An `awk` script that does the parsing of the fasta file.

I decided to post this here because it shows

1. How to do command line parsing of options in a shell script.
2. That it's possible to write an `awk` script, as opposed to just `awk`-"one-liners".

Assumptions:

- The sequence ID will occur directly after the `>` on the header line, followed by a space character.
- There is no spaces anywhere in the sequence data.

The script is called `extract.sh`.

To run, getting the sequence for sequence ID `gi1234` between positions 36 and 183 (inclusive):

```
$ sh extract.sh -i gi1234 -a 36 -b 183 <sequence.fa
ACAACAACAACACTGGGGGACACACTGGGACAACACTGGGGGACA
GGACACTGTACAACACTGGGTGTGTCGGGACAGTACACATGTTGGGGGGGTGTGTCGGACAACACTGGGGGACATGTGTG
TACAACACTGGGGGACAGTGACG
```

The output is unformatted. In this case I took the data in the question and inserted line-breaks after every 80th character before running the script.

The shell script (`extract.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
    cat <<USAGE_END
Usage:
    sh $0 -i seq_id -a start -b end <sequence.fa
USAGE_END
}

while getopts "a:b:i:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) start_pos="$OPTARG"  ;;
        b) end_pos="$OPTARG"    ;;
        i) seq_id="$OPTARG"     ;;
        *) usage; exit 1        ;;
    esac
done

if [ "x$seq_id" = "x" ]; then
    echo "Missing sequence ID (-i seq_id)"
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ "x$start_pos" = "x" -o "x$end_pos" = "x" ]; then
    echo "Missing either start or end coordinates (-a, -b)"
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "extract.awk" ]; then
    echo "Can not find the extract.awk AWK script!"
    exit 1
fi

awk -v id="$seq_id" -v a="$start_pos" -v b="$end_pos" -f extract.awk
```

The `awk` script (`extract.awk`):

```
# state == 0:   not yet at wanted sequence entry in file
# state == 1:   found sequence entry, not yet at start position
# state == 2:   found start position, not yet at end position

# off:  offset in sequence read so far

BEGIN   { state = 0 }

state == 0 && $0 ~ "^>" id " " {
    # We found the sequence entry we're looking for.
    state = 1;
    off = 0;
    next;
}

state > 0 && /^>/  {
    # New sequence header found while parsing sequence, terminate.
    exit;
}

state == 1 {
    len = length($0);

    if (len + off < a) {
        # Start position is not on this line.
        off += len;
        next;
    }

    state = 2;

    if (len + off >= b) {
        # Whole sequence is found on this line.
        print(substr($0, a - off, b - a + 1))
        exit;
    }

    # Output partial start of sequence.
    print(substr($0, a - off , len - (a - off) + 1))

    off += len;

    next;
}

state == 2 {
    len = length($0);

    if (off > b) {
        # (we should not arrive here)
        exit;
    }

    if (len + off < b) {
        # End position is not on this line.
        print($0);
        off += len;
        next;
    }

    # We found the end position, output line until end position
    # and terminate.
    print(substr($0, 1, b - off));
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was solving similar issue, but used to run in some trouble trying to use the scripts provided in one of the answers (both WSL, Mac)...

So I kept searching and found quite easy solution: It is the `getfasta` function from the `bedtools` suite!

https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you consider adding a link to the hompage of that software suite, so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily?